# Add synonyms/merge [.file-extension] and [file-extension]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Examples I found:

1. [wav](/questions/tagged/wav) [.wav](/questions/tagged/.wav)
2. [war](/questions/tagged/war) [.war](/questions/tagged/.war)
3. <s>[vdproj](/questions/tagged/vdproj) [.vdproj](/questions/tagged/.vdproj)</s>
4. [rdlc](/questions/tagged/rdlc) [.rdlc](/questions/tagged/.rdlc)
5. [ico](/questions/tagged/ico) [.ico](/questions/tagged/.ico)
6. [doc](/questions/tagged/doc) [.doc](/questions/tagged/.doc)

More difficult examples:

1. [mov](/questions/tagged/mov) has questions about file extensions (as [.mov](/questions/tagged/.mov))  and about assembler mov.

   [mov](/questions/tagged/mov) + [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) -> [assembly-mov](/questions/tagged/assembly-mov) ?
2. [.sdf](/questions/tagged/.sdf) has "DO NOT USE" wiki
3. [.emf](/questions/tagged/.emf) and [emf](/questions/tagged/emf) have different wikis. If misuses are often should be disambiguated
4. Not extension: [.each](/questions/tagged/.each) and [each](/questions/tagged/each), both have wiki about jQuery, but actually used for different languages(ruby/c#/powershell). Need change wiki to accept other languages or clean up to different tags

I believe more intuitive is to make tags with dot as master, but tags without dots have more questions.

Comment: Personally I don't like file-extension tags in general unless they're truly something important separately from the file extension.  [tag:microsoft-word] seems good enough for [tag:doc] for example, no?  Do we really get so many questions about the doc file format itself?  [tag:jpeg] is fine for [tag:jpg], and appropriate given the name of the standard.

Comment: @Joe, MS Word has few document types and I believe they may be different enough in programmatical generation. I don't know why we need [tag:ms-word] tag in this case, through

Comment: Ones with their "." intact are a little clearer.  Would `.txt` pop up if someone started typing "tx[...]", though?